# Bash - Printing out sentences line by line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have yet another `bash` question. If I have a file like...

```
Today is sunny. I like the sun. It is awesome!
```

And I want to print out each char until it hits a `?`, `.`, or `!`. can this also be a awk one liner? I want the printout to look like.

```
Today is sunny.
I like the sun.
It is awesome!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify the record separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="[.!?] *"} {print}'
```

Comment: That does work! although I still need it to print out the period after the sentence. Is there a way to do it by char, as in print char by char and then do something if it sees a (.,?, or !)?

Comment: sure, but I wouldn't use awk for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo Today is sunny. I like the sun. It is awesome! | sed 's/[.!?] */&\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something close in awk (not exactly want needed but interesting):

```
echo 'Today is sunny. I like the sun. It is awesome!'|awk '1' RS='[.,?]'
```

The canonical awk way:

```
echo 'Today is sunny. I like the sun. It is awesome!'|gawk 'a=gensub(/(\.|!|\?) */, "\\1\n", "g"){print a}'
```

Comment: Gold medal in shell golf!

Comment: @SzG to preseve chars you will need a formal sub . See my edited answer.Cheers

Answer (score 1):

a solution using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([\?\!\.]\)\s*/\1\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo Today is sunny. I like the sun. It is awesome! | awk '{gsub(/([?,.!])/,"&\n");print}'
```